# MySQL Connection not available when use SQLAlchemy(MySQL) and Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm getting this error sometime (sometime is ok, sometime is wrong):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available.
```

while using `session.query`

I'm writing a simple server with Flask and SQLAlchemy (MySQL). My `app.py` like this:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    try:
        session.query(Foo).all()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
```

**Update**
I also create new `session` in another file and call it in `app.py`

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

def foo_helper(): #call in app.py
    session.query(Something).all()
```

**Update 2**
My `engine`:

```
engine = create_engine('path')
```

How can I avoid that error?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you create `engine`? Are you sure your connection details are right?

Comment: And be sure that you have the necessary package to actually connect to MySQL.

Comment: I connect to MySQL successfully. My server run OK except it down, because that error, sometime (not always). I mean I'm sure the `engine` is right

Comment: Check out Flask-SQLAlchemy, it abstracts a lot of this away for you.

Comment: It means that you are trying to make connection but no connection available. Try to increase pool_size

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the value of ‘pool_recycle option’ is less than your MYSQLs wait_timeout value when using SQLAlchemy ‘create_engine’ function.

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://username:password@localhost/myDatabase", pool_recycle=3600)
```

Try to use `scoped_session` to make your session:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
```

and close/remove your session after retrieving your data.

```
session.query(Foo).all()
session.close()
```

Comment: By the last solution, you mean I will need to close and reopen everytime I query, don't you?

Comment: Yes. scoped_session offers all of the methods of the underlying Session via a proxy pattern, so you can call close() on scoped_session, which calls close() on the actual session, or you can call remove(), which emits close() then removes the Session object itself from the registry.  The latter has the advantage that any particular state established on the session, such as a Connection-based bind (see the example in http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction ), or other particular constructor options, are discarded