# Flask-SQLAlchemy -"MySQL Connection not available."

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

After about an hour of inactivity, any attempt to query the database hangs for about 30 seconds and then results in a 500 Internal Server Error. The basic error message is as follows:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available.
```

I've put the full stack trace at the end of the question.

Now I've visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891971/mysql-connection-not-available-when-use-sqlalchemymysql-and-flask) and tried the solution there, but to no avail. I've made the pool_recycle value greater than, equal to, and less than the MySQL timeout value (28800s currently).

What are some other things worth trying?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/auth.py", line 18, in login
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2445, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2281, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2516, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2531, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1078, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 188, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 181, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1073, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 556, in _init_compiled
    self.cursor = self.create_cursor()
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 745, in create_cursor
    return self._dbapi_connection.cursor()
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 847, in cursor
    return self.connection.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/benefits_app/benefits_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1383, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available. [SQL:'blah blah query']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got to an acceptable solution, but not a perfect one. The one only time this error occurred was when I was attempting to log in after a period of inactivity. My original code is as follows:

```
@auth_blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        except:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
```

Here is the change I made that stopped the 500 internal server errors from occurring.

```
@auth_blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
```

The reason this is not a perfect solution is that there is a delay while I wait for the first `User.query` to fail and try the same query again. It is also not very nice solution, but I no longer see an error message and the page works as intended even after an extended period of inactivity.

### UPDATE

As it turns out, the REAL solution that removed this error and made everything work great again was to change the MySQL wait_timeout and interactive_timeout from 28800 seconds down to the same value as my pool recycle option for sqlalchemy, which was set to 1600.

Problems Gone!

Answer (score 1):

Half the time you will probably need to host your application on a shared server where you dont have access to tune the mysql parameters.

and while my app was not timing out on my localhost ,when i ported it to python anywhere , i had inactivity errors and my solutions was this below

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:beautiful@localhost/service_compare'
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 280
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 20
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
```

You can read though here

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html

and on this line below

```
except:
        #db.session.rollback()
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
```

i think you need to add a db.session.remove()